# Seeking recommendations for client side simulation of server errors when fetching ember-data models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember-data (v10) with the RESTAdapter.  I want to be able to simulate HTTP 4xx and 5xx errors on the client side when fetching data from the server (i.e. App.Model.CalendarWeek.find(2)). but I am at a loss for how to do this.

Currently I use Jasmine and jasmine-fake-ajax for client side testing.

I am wondering how other developers test for these exceptional conditions?

Any recommendations or best practices?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jasmine-fake-ajax supports [configuration of HTTP response status codes.](https://github.com/mileskin/jasmine-fake-ajax#passing-data-to-successerror-handlers).

Alternately, the [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server) framework supports configuration of HTTP response status codes in fake XHR operations.